# Please, help me to connect a file that is in another folder in PHP script

Tags: php, require, fpdf

Figured out the error "FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream", FPDF class is in the folder `/ FPDF/fpdf.php`, but if I did I connect this way -

```
require ('/FPDF/fpdf.php');
```

Then an error PHP

> Fatal error: require () [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '.. / FPDF / fpdf.php' (include_path = '. :/ Usr / lib / php :/ usr /
>   local / lib / php') in /
>   home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20

**Tell me how to attach a file that is in another folder?**

*I tried to connect this way -*

```
require ($ _SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/ FPDF / fpdf.php');
```

But after that, in general, and covered with Warnings and Fatal Error (((

> Warning: require () [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in
>   effect. File (/ usr / local / apache / htdocs / FPDF / fpdf.php) is
>   not within the allowed path (s): (/ home / :/ usr / lib / php :/ tmp
>   :/ usr / share / locale) in /
>   home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20
>
> Warning: require (/ usr / local / apache / htdocs / FPDF / fpdf.php)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in
>   / home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20
>
> Fatal error: require () [function.require]: Failed opening required '/
>   usr / local / apache / htdocs / FPDF / fpdf.php' (include_path = '. :/
>   Usr / lib / php :/ usr / local / lib / php ') in /
>   home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20

Comment: Maybe the spaces are an issue? `/ FPDF / fpdf.php`?

Comment: There are no spaces in my script!

Comment: The code you posted would indicate there are: `/_FPDF_/_fpdf.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**open_basedir** is not active in your config php...

You can change this in your php.ini
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: thank you for answer, but I can't open php.ini, it's blocked by hosting. I write `require('/home/u552896297/public_html/FPDF/fpdf.php');` and It's work!